# how to instance Eq without deriving

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass

Sorry about my poor English. The title may not explain what I mean.

In Data.Tree, `Tree` is defined as following:

```
-- | Multi-way trees, also known as /rose trees/.
data Tree a = Node {
        rootLabel :: a,         -- ^ label value
        subForest :: Forest a   -- ^ zero or more child trees
    }
#ifdef __GLASGOW_HASKELL__
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show, Data)
#else
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
#endif
```

It uses `deriving` to instance `==` and `/=` for `Tree`(date).

Could I do the same thing without deriving? 
I try things like this:

```
data Test a = Test a
instance Eq Test where
    (Test a) == (Test b) = a == b
```

But It throws an exception. I think the reason is about the types of a and b.

And what can I do whether I want to define a custom action for my data with `==`.

I know I can use `Functor` with `fmap` to do it. But I want to use `==` like `a == b` where `a = Test 1` and `b = Test "a"`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **can define an `instance` of `Eq`** on `Tree` or `Test`, but there are *some* problems with your definition.

```
instance Eq Test where
    (Test a) == (Test b) = a == b
```

A first one is that `Test` in `Eq Test` is **still parametrized**. Indeed, you wrote `data Test a = ...` so that means that there is a *type* parameter. So you can specify it with:

```
instance Eq (Test a) where
    (Test y) == (Test x) = x == y
```

Now you thus specified that `Eq` is defined over `Test a`. I also renamed `a` and `b` to `x` and `y`. This is not necessary since the "type world" and "variable world" are separated, but it makes things less confusing.

But there is still a problem: you call `x == y`. But **there is no guantee that `a` itself is an instance of `Eq`**. You thus need to work with a *type constraint*:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Test a) where
    (Test y) == (Test x) = x == y
```

Now you specify that `Test a` is an instance of `Eq` *if* `a` is an instance of `Eq` as well.

For your `Tree` data structure, the `instance` of `Eq` should thus look like:

```
instance (Eq a, Eq (Forest a)) => Eq (Tree a) where
    (Tree x1 y1) == (Tree x2 y2) = x1 == x2 && y1 == y2
```

(of course I here define *how* two trees are equal, it is possible that you want to define the equality over two trees in a (semantically) different way, so you should not *per se* copy paste this code).

Note that - like [@luqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975200/how-to-instance-eq-without-deriving/43975450?noredirect=1#comment75007282_43975450) says - if `type Forest a = [Tree a]`, then you can *omit* the `Eq (Forest a)` type constraint since `instance Eq a => Eq [a]` holds. So in that case it is:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Tree a) where
    (Tree x1 y1) == (Tree x2 y2) = x1 == x2 && y1 == y2
```

Comment: N.B. `Forest a` is a type synonym for `[a]`, so technically the `Eq (Forest a)` constraint is not necessary, since `Eq a` already implies `Eq [a]`.  But this answer is clear given the question's parameters.

Comment: @luqui: you are right. I did not know a forest was defined as `[Tree a]` (well it was possible some additional fields were added). I added your note to the answer together with some comment. Thanks!

Comment: The last two instances lack `Eq` in `Eq (Tree a)`.

Comment: Thanks @chi for spotting that. Fixed.