# Haskell - "Ambiguous type variable" error on making my data an instance of Eq

Tags: haskell

I'm now learning Haskell and trying to make my data (which is similar to Maybe) an instance of `Eq`, as follows.

```
module Main where

data MyMaybe a = MyNothing | MyJust a

instance (Eq a) => Eq (MyMaybe a) where
  MyNothing == MyNothing = True
  MyJust x == MyJust y = x == y
  _ == _ = False

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let b0 = MyJust 42 == MyJust 42 -- OK
  print b0                        -- True
  let b1 = MyNothing == MyNothing -- Build error!
  print b1
```

But the complier returns an error in the line `let b1 = MyNothing == MyNothing` as follows.

> ? Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘==’
>       prevents the constraint ‘(Eq a0)’ from being solved.
>       Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
>       These potential instances exist:
>         instance Eq Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
>
> ...

How can I fix it?

... And I have searched existing questions and answers. The following one seemed close to mine, but I think that my code has already solved the points that the answer suggested.

[how to instance Eq without deriving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975200/how-to-instance-eq-without-deriving)

Comment: It has mothing to do with MyMaybe specifically,  you will get the same result with the standard Maybe. [Demo](https://ideone.com/VOeZak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `MyMaybe` is a parametrised type, but in the expression `MyNothing == MyNothing`, the compiler can't figure out if you meant `MyMaybe Int`, `MyMaybe String`, `MyMaybe (Int -> Bool)`, or something else.

You can help it with a type annotation like this:

```
let b1 = MyNothing == (MyNothing :: MyMaybe Int)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `MyNothing` has type `MyMaybe a` with no restrictions on what `a` can be.

When you write `MyNothing == MyNothing`, then the type of `(==) :: (Eq b) => b -> b -> Bool` restricts the two `MyNothing` to have the same type (the compiler initially starts out with `MyNothing :: MyMaybe a0` and `MyNothing :: MyMaybe a1`, but then realizes that `a0 == a1`).

But to resolve `==` itself, the compiler needs to find the right `Eq` instance (because that's where `==` is defined). Our type is `MyMaybe a`, which is good: We have an `Eq (MyMaybe a)` instance right there. But it also requires an `Eq a` instance, which cannot be resolved because we don't know what `a` is. (It doesn't matter that `(Eq a)` isn't actually used in the `MyNothing == MyNothing` case; type checking doesn't pay attention to runtime values.)

This is the point where the compiler gives up, saying it can't resolve the constraint `(Eq a0)` because the type variable `a0` is ambiguous.

---

Fixing this is easy. Just give the compiler a hint which type should be used:

```
let b1 = MyNothing == (MyNothing :: MyMaybe Integer)   -- for example
```

Or:

```
let b1 = MyNothing == (MyNothing :: MyMaybe (Double, [String]))
```

The actual type doesn't really matter (as long as it has an `Eq` instance).

---

This ambiguity isn't limited to your `MyMaybe` type. You should get the same error with `Maybe` (`Nothing == Nothing`) or `[]` (`[] == []`). In all cases there's a polymorphic constant involved (`Nothing :: Maybe a`, `[] :: [a]`).

---

Your example does actually work in ghci. This is because ghci uses [extended defaulting rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci) and ends up converting `a` to `()`; i.e. the comparison is done as `MyNothing == (MyNothing :: MyMaybe ())`.